# Printing Questions/Responses in READABLE scale

Tags: support

I've posted about this before. I have the Meltdown/Spectre cpu flaw. I'm trying to update the kernel to a patched version.

I found an AskUbuntu page I want to print. Printed at "200" the words scroll off the right edge of the page are are unviewable, let alone readable.

When I set the print to "100", the words are so small as to be unreadable as to size.

What goes on with this? Is bandwidth (and therefore $) being saved with this tiny type size? I was recently admonished at another Linux forum to not post in such small type size. That was an accident as I could not have known the default board's type size.

Ask Ubuntu needs a radio print button which prints in easy (easier) to read text size.

Thnx.